# Uploading Images to Firestore as a 9B file

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I was trying to upload an image to my firebase storage its uploading as a 9b file and i cannot open it. its snot showing any error message. it uploads and gives the url. but in the url its broken and shows error loading preview in firebase storage

```
/** @type {any} */
        const metadata = {
          contentType: 'image/png',
         
        };

        // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
        const storageRef = ref(storage, 'products/' + file.name);
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata);

        // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
        uploadTask.on('state_changed',
          (snapshot) => {
            
            // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
            const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
            switch (snapshot.state) {
              case 'paused':
                console.log('Upload is paused');
                break;
              case 'running':
                console.log('Upload is running');
                break;
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            // A full list of error codes is available at
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
            switch (error.code) {
              case 'storage/unauthorized':
                // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                break;
              case 'storage/canceled':
                // User canceled the upload
                break;

              // ...

              case 'storage/unknown':
                // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
                break;
            }
          },
          () => {
            // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
            getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
              console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
});
```

Comment: Where is file defined? Can you share the complete code? Most commonly it's dude to file being undefined

Comment: @Dharmaraj can you check this please https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E4KOB6lRDSYYcQUHRQpxec1IPQmyCzz5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In the upload function you should check if user has actually selected file. Also try using `uploadBytes` function instead:

```js
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";

var fileImage1 = $("#chooseImg").val();

if (!file) {
  console.log("No File Selected")
} else {
  const storageRef = ref(storage, 'products/' + file.name);

  uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
  });
}
```

Comment: i tried this brother but still uploading as a 9B file :( :( can u help me

Comment: @Afrij can you `console.log(file)` right before `uploadBytes` and share a screenshot of output ?

Comment: ,I tried some ways still not working , https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IZ1-Vzb-ShZv_hYgFAwAa5zKk6datdp1/view

Comment: @Afrij did u try logging the file? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes it's correct , can u please check my code , https://drive.google.com/file/d/101S8p2gLRuK4bn5BVqJl385ssEQChA3W/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata);
```

the `file` variable you are passing to upload contains the wrong type of data. Make sure it's a `Blob` and not some other data type. I was trying to upload the result of `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` and it behaved the same ~ just 9b of metadata.